# Inputting a number into a recursion function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sum_all(n):

    number = input("number pls ")
    if n > 1:
        return n + sum_all(n-1)
    elif n == 1: 
        return 1
    else:
        raise Exception("negative number")

print(sum_all(number))
```

I cant figure out for the life of me how to get this to accept me inputting a number in python 3

Comment: `print(sum_all(int(input())))`

Comment: Move the line of input out of function

Answer (score 1):

you do not use the number variable in any place of your method. I think what you want to do is something like this>

```
def sum_all(n):

    if n > 1:
        return n + sum_all(n-1)
    elif n == 1: 
        return 1
    else:
        raise Exception("negative number")

number = int(input("number pls "))

print(sum_all(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

What is currently happening is the first thing being called is `sum_all(number)`. The value in `number` will be passed into `sum_all` as the parameter `n`. However, `number` isn't defined outside the function `sum_all` so the code will throw an error similar to the following:

```
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

Now, the question becomes what are you actually trying to do? Do you want to keep getting user inputs and adding those inputs together? If this is the case, then you don't need recursion for this. You can use a simple loop.

If you want to get the input once and then get the sum of that input, then you need recursion. But if you need the input only once - then you should only be calling it once - not every time you go through the function. Let's illustrate this with a a call to `sum_all(5)`:

```
sum_all(5):
| sum_all(4):
| | sum_all(3):
| | | sum_all(2):
| | | | sum_all(1):
| | | | | return 1
| | | | return 2 + 1
| | | return 3 + 3
| | return 4 + 6
| return 5 + 10
```

This means with an input of `5`, `sum_all` returns `15`. If this is what you intend to do, then you should only be getting `input` once, outside of the function `sum_all`, and be passing the value input by the user into `sum_all`.